# Thread bumping in the Stack Exchange universe

Tags: discussion

Just wondering how people feel about thread bumping on the stack exchange sites. I personally think it is a time honored way to get feed back on a subject that is not receiving enough attention, but I got lambasted the other day for bumping one me my questions (which was a pretty good one I think).

Comment: Link to your question?

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: i did not link to my question because i am not looking to have it judged specifically, but rather the pratice of thread bumping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not completely discouraged.  If you would like to bump a question, try to add some value with your edit.

Continually bumping a question though can be frowned upon, as it looks like you are just looking to get more votes.

Comment: I agree, over bumping is just annoying, but a bump every day or two for in a thread with little or no activity doesn't seem like that big of a deal, certainly not warranting a down vote.

Comment: @typo, Meh, people can downvote whatever they want.  If they think its annoying to see that question every day, you may get an downvote.

Answer (score 5):

As it says in https://stackoverflow.com/faq

> In order to get good answers, you have to put some effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

The key thing here is **add value with your edit**.

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly acceptable behaviour - as long as you don't overdo it.

In fact the Community user bumps a few unanswered (no upvoted answers) questions each day.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like to see a bunch of bumps in a thread either, but I think one every day or two (if the thread has no replies) is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want more attention given to your question, try adding a bounty. That will generate more views and responses.

Comment: Point taken.  The person who got all bent out of shape for me bumping said the same thing.